# Internal string resource references

Tags: android, resources

I wonder if it's possible to reference a XML string value in another XML String resource.

Things like the following are possible:

```
<string name="title">MyTitle</string>
<string name="activityTitle">@string/title</string>
```

But in case of an concated resource string, I found no solution yet, so what I'm searching for is the following:

```
<string name="title">MyTitle</string>
<string name="subTitle">@string/title - mySubTitle</string>
```

So far I was only able to solve it programmically via:

```
<string name="title">MyTitle</string>
<string name="subTitle">%1$s - mySubTitle</string>
getResources().getString(R.string.subTitle, getResources().getString(R.string.title));
```

I would like to keep the string references in the string.xml file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not supported at this time, AFAIK.